Running Apps Script code - not working for fetching the email of other editor to whom access was granted
function onEdit(e) {
    const range = e.range;
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    const editedColumn = range.getColumn();
    const editedRow = range.getRow();

    // Check if the edit is in column A
    if (editedColumn === 1) {
        // If content is deleted in column A, clear the corresponding cell in column F
        if (range.isBlank()) {
            sheet.getRange(editedRow, 6).clearContent(); // Clear content in column F
        } else if (editedRow > 1) { // Avoid clearing header row
            // Get the email of the editor
            const editorEmail = e.user.email;

            // Update the corresponding cell in column F with the editor's email
            sheet.getRange(editedRow, 6).setValue(editorEmail);
        }
    }
}

once the changes are made in the column A in the Google sheets - email of the editor should automatically displayed on the column F, currently it working only for me but not showing the email of the second editor to whom I granted permission

This question was answered previously by user Anton Dementiev here and applies to the e.user.email as well.

Here's what Google documentation says about the Session class
The Session class provides access to session information, such as the
user's email address (in some circumstances) and language setting.
In regards to 'getActiveUser()' method, it states
If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity,
User.getEmail() returns a blank string. The circumstances in which the
email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address
is not available in any context that allows a script to run without
that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e)
trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to
"execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the
user). However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the
developer and the user belong to the same G Suite domain.
Because you use the simple trigger - onEdit() - the code will not
execute unless explicitly authorized by the user. For installable
triggers, that would mean executing the function manually from the
script editor.
You can publish the project as a sheets add-on. In this case, users
will be asked to grant permissions declared in the add-on manifest.
More info
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session

